# Fetch column name from SQL QUERY STRING in PHP

Tags: php

I want to fetch the alias column names from a query. Here I have not executed the query yet. The query is just in string format.

```
$query= "select id as id,name as 'Full_Name',caddress as 'Company_Address',paddress as 'Permenant_Address' from users"
```

From above query I want results like: id, Full_Name, Company_Address, Permenant_Address

I have tried to make it using explode function but it gives quite different results as I expect.

```
print_r(explode('as',$str));

O/P: Array ( [0] => select id [1] => id,name [2] => 'Full_Name',caddress [3] => 'Company_Address',paddress [4] => 'Permenant_Address' from users )
```

How to achieve the exact output I wanted?

Comment: This can, of course, be done, but why would you want to do this? There are two reasons doing this doesn't make sense: 1. You're making the query string, surely you must already know what the aliasses are. 2. When you execute the query the result could contain the aliasses, so you don't need to know them in advance.

Comment: My comment was intended to elicit an explanation from you. Not because I want to be awkward, but because I fear you might be trying to solve the wrong problem. If you provide a bit more context we might better understand why you would want to do this. If you have a good reason I might even show you how to do it.

Comment: That is perfectly alright. May be describing in detail, i can get the direct solution. I am doing this because i am using the datatable and generating it using the ajaxcall. Now, what i want to do is, i want to populate the HEADER or TITLE of the table automatically. but as on my research and by failing multiple tries, i felt that it will not quite possible to direct populate from datatatble. So, what i want to do is, from this query i will store the alias names into an array and then print as header in php.

Comment: If you're using MySQLi then you can use [fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) on the result to get the rows in arrays who's keys are the aliases. If you're using PDO then the same can be achieved with [fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as the fetch style.

Comment: If you're analysing arbitrary code, writing a reliable SQL parser can be a life's project. As an anecdote, the SQL parsing routines account for [a large part of MySQL Workbench's codebase](https://mysqlworkbench.org/2015/08/parsing-in-mysql-workbench/). But getting the column names of a result set is trivial. Thus KIKO's comments. I think you should edit the question and explain your ultimate goal. If you really have a JavaScript library that sends SQL over the wire, you might have a potential security breech.